# How to use ` in ` in bash

Tags: bash

Is there a way to use ` inside a ` in bash script

This works

```
echo `echo '(!1)*2' | bc -l`
```

but this doesnt

```
echo `echo '(!`echo 1`)*2' | bc -l`
```

the error is

```
unmatched '
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `$()` instead of ``` `` ```:

```
$ echo $(echo $(echo $(echo "Hello") world)! )
```

Or the solution to your answer:

```
$ echo $(echo "( ! $(echo 1) )*2" | bc -l)
```

p.s. don't use `'` when you want to make use of variables inside a string. Only double quotes `"` are parsed.